# How to use JS to control what is returned by an included HTML file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use jQuery to load re-usable portions of HTML:

```
$("#menu-header").load("include/menu_header.html");
```

This should return a list of navigation page numbers that look something like this:

```
<span class="menu-link">
    <a href="./menu1.html">1</a>
</span>
<span class="menu-link">
    <a href="./menu2.html">2</a>
</span>
```

What I'm trying to do is to remove the `<a>` tag for the current page. So if the browser is currently on page `menu2.html` the link to the second page shouldn't be a link, just normal text instead.

Here is what I try to do in `include/menu_header.html`:

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script>
    cur_page_fname = location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    if (cur_page_fname == 'menu1.html') {
        document.write(
                '<span class="menu-link">1</span>');
        document.write(
                '<span class="menu-link"> <a href="./menu2.html">2</a> </span>');
    } else if (cur_page_fname == 'menu2.html') {
        document.write(
                '<span class="menu-link"> <a href="./menu1.html">1</a> </span>');
        document.write(
                '<span class="menu-link">2</span>');
    }
</script>
```

But what this does is it--for a moment--shows the page without the navigation menu, then immediatly changes to a white page that has nothing except the navigation menu, and no CSS is applied. This navigation menu looks as intended, but how do I make the navigation menu within the normal page?

Comment: The main problem is using `document.write()` on a fully loaded page (there are other issues as well), but you're going to get a momentary "navigationless" page (a-la "FOUC") if you use dynamic loading anyway, so I suggest you look for a different approach altogether. Why not construct the page on the server?

Comment: Don't use document.write. You are using jquery anyway - so use it to create the DOM and append it to where needed.

Comment: @Amit The "server" is an embedded WLAN module with capabilities much more limited than a browser's, so I should construct on the client-side.

Comment: BTW - Why do you include jquery again in `menu_header.html` - obviously it is already included by the main page since you use it to load the menu.

Comment: I agree with Igal. If you really want to do this client-side, download the content of your .html file, make it into a jquery object by passing it as a string and voila, you have full access to all jQuery functionality to manipulate it. Once you are done manipulating and the DOM is ready (I suggest doing the download before document.ready for obvious performance), append it where you need.

Comment: @WardD.S. and @Igal S. Thanks for the tip. Do you mean in `menu_header.html` I should turn `menu1.html` (this is the file that loads `menu_header.html`) into a JQuery object and manipulate that? I'm confused where I should be doing the object construction, the manipulating, and the appending.

Comment: I'd still say you're taking a wrong approach. If you have such limited "server" capabitilites, and you have a static site (static as in no server interaction or manipulating, pure content server), have your HTML files pre-baked. You can use separate files for componentization in you development environment, but you should distribute complete, static HTML files.

Comment: @Amit Thanks for the advice, but the site isn't static. I'm developing a web-app that will have a user interacting with a device, so front-end manipulation will translate to stuff being done on the backend. e.g. values shown on a page will be read from the device's backend. All I have on the backend is C and only 4MB space, which is why I want to do all web-app stuff on the front-end.

Comment: I still think this is generally the wrong approach, but see my answer as an alternative that leans towards your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#menu-header").load("include/menu_header.html");
```

Gets called after the page loads.   Then you call:

```
document.write(...
```

Which starts writing to a new page since the page has already been rendered.   If you create menu_header.html as such:

```
<span class="menu-link menu1"> <a href="./menu1.html">1</a> </span>
<span class="menu-link menu2"> <a href="./menu2.html">2</a> </span>
```

...and then call the load function as follows:

```
$("#menu-header").load("include/menu_header.html", function() {
    cur_page_fname = location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    if (cur_page_fname == 'page1.html') {
        $('span.menu2 a').replaceWith(function(){
            return $("<span>" + $(this).html() + "</span>");
        });
    }
    if (cur_page_fname == 'page2.html') {
        $('span.menu1 a').replaceWith(function(){
            return $("<span>" + $(this).html() + "</span>");
        });
    }
});
```

You should achieve the desired results.

Comment: It works! Many thanks for your help! You've taught me something about manipulating DOM with JQuery. But the `function()` argument that you pass: why didn't you pass the parameters `String responseText, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR` [as requested by the API](http://api.jquery.com/load/)?

Comment: The function runs when the load is complete.   It fills the current page with the specified HTML and then the function changes it in place.

Comment: If anything, I'd load the content as text, put that into a DocumentFragment, manipulate that and then move into the real page to avoid an extra step of visual jitter.

Comment: True.   I left out any polish on the approach to keep it simple.   You could make #menu-header hidden in CSS and .show() it as the last step too.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use asynchronous dynamic loading, use a simple script element:

#### menu_header.js

```
cur_page_fname = location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
if (cur_page_fname == 'menu1.html') {
    document.write(
            '<span class="menu-link">1</span>');
    document.write(
            '<span class="menu-link"> <a href="./menu2.html">2</a> </span>');
} else if (cur_page_fname == 'menu2.html') {
    document.write(
            '<span class="menu-link"> <a href="./menu1.html">1</a> </span>');
    document.write(
            '<span class="menu-link">2</span>');
}
```

#### menu1.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>whatever</div>
<div id="menu-header"><script src="menu_header.js"></script></div>
<div>whatever else</div>
</body>
</html>
```

That way you avoid the momentary missing navigation section since the script is executed synchronously when the page is loaded.

Comment: This is another great approach; I didn't know you could source .js scripts like that. Thanks for your answer. I guess you mean my method is asynchronous because the manipulation is performed *after* the document is ready?

Comment: Yes. it uses an AJAX request, and upon completion executes whatever code is necessary to add elements to the page. This way it's unavoidable that you'll see a partial page first. The advantage of using the other suggested method is that you get to keep your menu header as an HTML instead of javascript and that might be simpler to edit / design.

Answer (score 1):

Try this if it works. I made it on paper so you need to test if it work perfect

```
$("#menu-header").load("include/menu_header.html", function(html) {
    var $menu = jQuery(html),
    currentURI = window.location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/");


   $menu.find("[href='./"+currentURI+"']").attr("href","#");

   // Do whatever you want to do with $menu

});
```